# C code generated by Zig fails link stage due to missing functions (soft-float)

Tags: c, undefined-reference, transpiler, zig

I have a program written in Zig, but the system where it will run don't have a Zig compiler.

I export the program to C code (via the `ofmt = c` feature) then compile it with either *gcc* or *clang*.

Which worked well, until I used floats.

I have the following error:

```
undefined reference to `__floatundisf'
undefined reference to `__floatundidf'
undefined reference to `__fixdfsi'
undefined reference to `__floatsidf'
undefined reference to `__fixunsdfsi'
undefined reference to `__floatunsidf'
```

After investigation, those functions are meant to replace assemble instructions in case floats operations are not available on the targeted CPU.

Interestingly, when compiling with Zig's C compiler (`zig cc`), it works. But both *gcc* (13.2.1) and *clang* (16.0.6) fail to provide implementation during linking. I tried to link against different libraries like *libc*, *libm* and *libgcc*, which the latest, is supposed to provide them.

Here is my `build.zig`:

```
const target = b.standardTargetOptions(.{});
const optimize = b.standardOptimizeOption(.{});

const exe = b.addExecutable(.{
    .name = "zigc",
    .root_source_file = .{ .path = "src/main.zig" },
    .target = target,
    .optimize = optimize,
});
b.installArtifact(exe);

const c_source = b.addStaticLibrary(.{
    .name = "zigc",
    .root_source_file = .{ .path = "src/main-c.zig" },
    .target = .{ .ofmt = .c },
    .optimize = optimize,
});
const c_export = b.addInstallArtifact(c_source, .{});
const export_step = b.step("cc", "Export to C code");
export_step.dependOn(&c_export.step);
```

Comment: What was your linking command? Also, `zig cc` worked on your developer machine, not on the target one (which doesn't have Zig compiler)?

Comment: It turns out, by running `zig cc --verbose`, it gives the invocation to `ld` where it adds an object file `zig/compiler_rt.o` which contains the missing functions

Answer (score 2):

By running `zig cc` with the `--verbose` option, it gives the linker (`ld`) invocation:

```bash
ld ... libcompiler_rt.a ...
```

Skipping all the uninteresting parts, one argument is important. Zig ships a bunch of functions in a library called `libcompiler_rt`.

The sources of the library are in `zig/lib/compiler_rt.zig` and the folder of the same name. To produce a portable C code export of this library, compile it with:

```bash
zig build-obj -ofmt=c compiler_rt.zig
```

Now you can compile the program with:

```bash
gcc main.zig.c compiler_rt.c
```